# Is there a way we might face race condition when running async tasks on serial queue

Tags: swift, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue

Suppose if multiple async tasks running in a serial queue are accessing a same shared resource, are there any chances we might face race condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comment I've added, this is taken from [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html). In bold I put the emphasis to what you are looking for.

> Serial queues (also known as private dispatch queues) execute one task
>   at a time in the order in which they are added to the queue. The
>   currently executing task runs on a distinct thread (which can vary
>   from task to task) that is managed by the dispatch queue. **Serial
>   queues are often used to synchronize access to a specific resource**.

If you are using  a concurrent queue instead you could have a race condition. You can prevent it using dispatch barriers, for example. See [Grand Central Dispatch In-Depth: Part 1/2](https://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1) for more details.

For `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` the same applies. `NSOperationQueue` can be made serial with `maxConcurrentOperationCount` set to `1`. In addition, using dependencies through operations, you can synchronize the access to a shared resource.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer. I will go through the links. As you pointed out in bold that is what everybody says but what if there are two async tasks running on a serial queue making changes to common resource then we might face race condition know?

Comment: @Kishoretheju Nope, since the resource can be touched serially. A first task access the resource, when this finishes, the other one can touch it. By construction, this is enforced by a serial structure like the serial queue.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not run into a race condition, see what I did there, when running async tasks on a serial queue due to the fact that the type of queue has to deal with the ways the tasks are executed and while synchrony and asynchrony has to deal with the responsiveness of your application when completing an expensive task.

The reason it is easy to run into a race condition when on a concurrrent queue because on a concurrent queue tasks are allowed to be executed at the same time therefore different threads sometimes may be "racing" to perform an action and in all actuality they are overwriting the previous threads work due to the threads performing the same action. Where as on a serial queue tasks are executed one at a time so two threads cant race to complete a task because it happens in sequential order. Hope that helps!